# In CouchDB, how can I emit a key value in a reduce function?

Tags: json, couchdb, reduce

Currently, my code looks like

```
function(keys, values, rereduce){
    return {"key":keys[0][0],"count":values.length};
}
```

Upon running this, the resulting row is:

```
key = None, value={u'count':3,u'key':u'123456'}
```

This works for my purposes, as I just parse the JSON string in the value attribute, but it seems like the wrong way to be doing things.

So how can I have the reduce function emit a key value, rather than None?

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is valid only for first reduce. It fails for rereduce. Read [Introduction to CouchDB Views: 1.2.2 Reduce Functions](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Reduce_Functions). Notice the first argument (`key`) of the `reduce()` declaration when the third argument (`rereduce`) is `true`.

I also thing that your `count` will not work as you expect for `rereduce==true`. It should sum up the counts from earlier reduces, not count the counts

Answer (score 0):

Not enough context to be sure, but you might be thinking of reduce functions differently then how they're intended. [From the CouchDB guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/views.html):

> If you don’t reduce your values to a single scalar value or a small fixed-sized object or array with a fixed number of scalar values of small sizes, you are probably doing it wrong.

Your example does reduce down to something small, but that looks like coincidence. If you want to output some kind of key, you might need a map function. Or, to rethink what you're doing and how it fits into the MapReduce model.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was happening. The reduce function was creating one single scalar value, whereas what I wanted was a list of key-value pairs. This was happening because I wasn't using [grouping](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Grouping).

By adding the 'group=true' argument to my query, using _count as my reduce now produces

```
key = 123456, value=3
```

No grouping means that all data was reduced to a single, scalar value. By enabling grouping, things are only reduced with items that have the same key value, which is what I wanted.

Comment: As noted by Marcin Skórzewski, your reduce will fail randomly because you do not check the value of rereduce.

Comment: I also noticed that. I re-wrote the function to accommodate re-reduce, but after finding about the group=true argument, I am now just using _count, rather than any sort of custom reduce function.

Comment: Great. Built-in reduce functions are almost always the best choice. For example, I use `_stats` even when I only need a single value like `max`.